# Test for corrupted list

Tags: c, linked-list

Suppose I receive a list in a volatile environment, where the tail element is only partially filled with accessible items; further, passing on/deleting/dropping the element is a perfectly adequate solution.

So,

```
next->A // is unaccessible
next->B // is accessible

if (next->A) // evaluates to true
```

is there a method to test and pass/delete this list element?

Comment: What does "volatile environment", "accessible elements", "dumping an element" even mean in the context of C?

Comment: Add "only partially filled" to that list of obfuscating terms.

Comment: So I am parsing packets--the packets are 'volatile' in the sense that they have a set format, but bits get flipped, corrupted, the packets may be incomplete, etc.  Dumping: I just delete the element recursively and set next to NULL

Comment: You really need to reword the question and add much more context and code.

Comment: What exactly are each element? Show how they are defined.

Comment: So, basically, you're receiving a data structure where touching anything could result in undefined behaviour, and you want to write code to deal with it in a well-defined manner?

Comment: @NPE yup; plus, I am restricted to O(1) options.

Comment: In this case you need to define some integrity-checking protocol. You won't get away that easily.

Comment: `... in the sense that they have a set format, but bits get flipped, corrupted, the packets may be incomplete` The goal of you *parsing* the packets is to handle these cases: set the fields to default values(or pointers to NULL), or set flags to indicate that the fields inside the packet are invalid or absent.

Comment: @joop yes, i am debugging segfaults in an open-source packet parsing solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C does not provide a built-in way of testing if a memory location is accessible or not. You cannot check if `next->A` is available for the same reason that you cannot check if a pointer is "dangling".

A fix to this is to add a level of indirection: make a list of "envelope" objects which are always available. Each envelope holds a pointer to the actual object, along with a flag indicating object's accessibility. This way the provider of the list would be able to manipulate the flag independently of the data object itself, without disturbing the content of the list:

[image: List of envelopes]

Comment: Awesome--thanks man.  If there was such a test, that would have been ideal.  I've got a print statement deeper in the code that is indicating there may be an entry point for adding such a flag, although an entire envelope might be out of scope, appreciate the negative affirmation!